# Specifying path with whitespace in eclipse on mac os

Tags: eclipse-pde, eclipse-plugin

I need to mention a path variable in eclipse Helios on Mac Os.

The path I am specifying contains whitespace in it.
Example:

```
user/folder/android sdk
```

I have tried following ways which failed in the end:
Specifying path in quotes both single & double.

Can anyone suggest way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any issue with classpath including spaces, on Mac Os or any other Os:

Add your space [through the Gui](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jar) ([Java Build Path](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm))

[image: Java Build Path Gui]

, and you will get a .classpath file with:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="my libs/apache_cli/lib/commons-cli-1.0.jar" 
                           sourcepath="my libs/apache_cli/src/commons-cli-src.zip"/>
```

The quotes take care of any spaces in the paths.